# Find a perpendicular bisector line that makes a perfect X with the given line segment

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus

I have a line segment formed by the points $(-5, -3)$ and $(0, 7)$. I need to find another line segment which is perpendicular to the first one and makes a perfect X. By perfect X I mean that both line segments are same length

Here's what I did so far:

1 - Calculate the equation for the line, starting with slope

$m = \frac{10}{5}$

solving for b in $y = mx + b$:

$7 = 2*0+ b => b = 7$

Ok, so now I found the equation of the first line:

$$y = 2x + 7$$

I also calculated the midpoint which is

$$(-2.5, 2)$$

To find the other line perpendicular to this one I used the slope property (negative inverse):

$$-1/m$$

Plugin in the values for the mid point:

$$2 = - \frac{1}{2} * \frac{5}{2} + b$$
$$b = \frac{3}{4}$$

So the perpendicular line to $y = 2x + 7$ at the midpoint $(-2.5, 2)$

$$y = - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{4}$$

The problem now is that I'm supposed to give the line segment, not an infinite line. How do I get the start and end points of this perpendicular line?  basically I need to find the blue points below somehow, I'm just not sure how to go about this

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with using vectors?

Comment: @DavidQuinn how would I use them is this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MidPoint of $X=(-5,-3)$ & $Y=(0,7)$ is $M=((-5+0)/2,(-3+7)/2)=(-5/2,2)$

Now , shift the Points such that $M$ is at the Origin.

Then $X$ is shifted to $U=(-5+5/2),(-3-2)=(-5/2,-5)$
& $Y$ is shifted to $V=(0+5/2),(7-2)=(5/2,5)$

When Point $(A,B)$ is rotated by $90^0$ around the Origin, it becomes $(-B,A)$
Hence when we rotate $U$ & $V$ , we will get $(5,-5/2)$ & $(-5,5/2)$

Now , we shift $U$ & $V$ after rotation , back to Original Location $M$ :
$(5-5/2,-5/2+2)$ & $(-5-5/2,5/2+2)$
$(5/2,-1/2)$ & $(-15/2,9/2)$

The line Segment between $X$ & $Y$ will intersect the line Segment between $(5/2,-1/2)$ & $(-15/2,9/2)$ which will be the "X" we want.

This is the Image :
[image: X]

Answer (score 2):

HINT…$$\overrightarrow{MB}=\left(\begin{matrix}2.5\\5\end{matrix}\right)$$

So if the points you seek are $P$ and $Q$,

$$\overrightarrow{MP}=\pm\left(\begin{matrix}-5\\2.5\end{matrix}\right)$$

Can you take it from there?